# How to setState() when listening to socket.io server on reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, setstate

I developed a socket.io server that sends data every 10 seconds to the client. Socket.io client is used in an application that I created with ReactJs class component. I connected to the socket in `componentDidMount` and listened for the socket in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
let socket = null
 
class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            stateData: null
        }
    }
 
    componentDidMount() {
        socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        // calling some method
    }
 
    componentDidUpdate( {
        if(socket !== null) {
            socket.on("positionUpdates", (data) => {
                // console log to check if the data was connected successfully and the time when it got the data
                console.log("connected", data, new Date())
                this.setState({stateData: data})
            })
        }  
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
     
        )
    }
}
```

I will save the data that I get from the socket into a state using `setState()`. But I ran into a strange thing when running the code. I made a `console.log` after `socket.on`. `console.log` should happen once every 10 seconds when the data is retrieved. But what happens is that the `console.log` is displayed multiple times. When I remove the `setState`, the code normally runs again.

How should I do `setState` when listening to socket.io server on socket.io client?

Answer (score 1):

So from my understanding of socket.io's `on` listener, is that you can listen the same event but with different functions.

So you can do something like

```
socket.on("event1", () => console.log("this is my 1st listener"))
socket.on("event1", () => console.log("this is the 2nd listener but with same event name"))
```

So after everytime you set state the `componentDidUpdate` gets fired and `socket.on("positionUpdates", (data) => {...})` registers the `positionUpdates` event multiple times.

So to fix this move your `socket.on`s to componentDidMount and also make sure to off the listener after unmount.

```
eventHandlerFunc(data) {
    // do something with data
},
componentDidMount() {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on("event name", eventHandlerFunc);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
    socket.off("event name", eventHandlerFunc)     
}
```